# SQL Select employees with at least 2 orders with at least one of which is in a certain district, without nested SQL blocks

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, 'Customers' and 'Employees' that are joined over the third table 'Orders'

```
| CustomerID | CDistrict |    | EmployeeID | EName |
|------------|-----------|    |------------|-------|
|      1     |     A     |    |      1     |  Alex |
|      2     |     A     |    |      2     |  Bob  |
|      3     |     B     |    |      3     |  Edd  |
|      4     |     C     |

| OrderID | CustomerID | EmployeeID |
|---------|------------|------------|
|    1    |      1     |      1     |
|    2    |      3     |      1     |
|    3    |      3     |      2     |
|    4    |      5     |      2     |
|    5    |      1     |      3     |
```

How do I select the names of all employees who have served at least 2 orders, at least of which was for a customer from the district 'A' *without nested SQL Blocks*? That is, result should be 'Alex'. 
I managed to do this with a nested query, as follows:

```
SELECT EName FROM Database.Employees
WHERE 
    EmployeeID IN 
    (SELECT EmployeeID FROM Database.Orders
        GROUP BY EmployeeID
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
AND
    EmployeeID IN
    (SELECT EmployeeID FROM Database.Orders
        WHERE 
            CustomerID IN
            (SELECT CustomerID FROM Database.Customers
                WHERE CDistrict = 'A'));
```

However, I need to do this without the nested queries. 
My query to select all employees who have served at least 2 orders looks like:

```
SELECT EName FROM Database.Employees, Database.Orders
WHERE 
    Employees.EID = Orders.EID
    GROUP BY EName HAVING COUNT(OrderID) >=2
ORDER BY EName;
```

My query to select all employees who have served a customer from the district 'A' looks like:

```
SELECT EName FROM Database.Employees, Database.Orders, Database.Customers
WHERE 
    Employees.EID = Orders.EID
    AND
    Orders.CID = Customers.CID
    AND
    CDistrict = 'A';
```

However, when I try to join these queries into a single query like

```
SELECT EName FROM Database.Employee, Database.Orders, Database.Customers
WHERE 
    Employees.EID = Orders.EID
    AND
    Orders.CID = Customers.CID
    AND
    CDistrict = 'A'
    GROUP BY EName HAVING COUNT(OrderID) >=2;
```

I become 0 results. I figured, this query probably searches for all employees, who have served at least 2 orders in the district 'A', but this is not what I need - I need employees who have served at least two orders, at least one of which was in the district 'A'. What am I doing wrong? How do I translate my nested query into a regular query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT o.EmployeeID
FROM Database.Orders o JOIN
     Database.Customers c
     ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY o.EmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 AND
       SUM(c.CDistrict = 'A') > 0;
```

Comment: This almost works, but I need the name of the employee, not the ID

Comment: @ZyTelevan . . . You should be able to join back to the `Employees` table to get the name (remember to include the name in the `GROUP BY`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E.EName 
FROM Employees E INNER JOIN Orders O 
     ON O.EmployeeID=E.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Customers C 
     ON C.CustomerID=O.CustomerID 
WHERE C.CDistrict='A' 
GROUP BY E.EmployeeID 
HAVING COUNT(O.CustomerID) >= 2
```